# Send confirmation message from pc2 to pc1 unicast

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Good morning, I have this code done, in which the job is to send a message from pc1 to pc3, with an interlocutor in the middle (pc2). When pc2 receives message from pc1, it sends a message reception for pc. When pc3 receives the message, it send for pc2 the confirmation that in turn send to pc1. Sending the message from pc2 to pc3 is via broadcast. Everything else is unicast, however in my code I have sent the confirmation from pc2 to pc1 also by broadcast. Can someone help me to change the code? Thank you.

pc2 code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define exit_on_error(s,m) if (s < 0) { perror(m); exit(1); }
 #define MAX_BUFFER 512

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    int sock, length, fromlen, r, send_sock, sendlen, V = 1, n; //int n declarado
    struct sockaddr_in SERVER_ADDR;
    struct sockaddr_in FROM_ADDR;
    struct sockaddr_in SENDTO_ADDR;
    //struct sockaddr_in LOCALMENTE_addr;
    char buf[MAX_BUFFER];

    //verifica argumentos
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("USAGE: %s <a.porto> <ip_broadcast> <c.porto> <b.porto>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    //cria socket UDP
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0) printf("SOCKET");
    length = sizeof(SERVER_ADDR);
    bzero(&SERVER_ADDR, length);
    SERVER_ADDR.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SERVER_ADDR.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    SERVER_ADDR.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &V, sizeof(V));
    sendlen = sizeof(SENDTO_ADDR);
    bzero(&SENDTO_ADDR, sendlen);
    SENDTO_ADDR.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SENDTO_ADDR.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
    SENDTO_ADDR.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3]));

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&SERVER_ADDR,length) < 0) printf("BIND:  ");

    fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while(1)
    {

    printf("Wait for the next message...!\n");
    bzero(&buf, MAX_BUFFER);
    n = recvfrom(sock,buf,MAX_BUFFER,0,(struct sockaddr *) &FROM_ADDR, &fromlen);



    if (strstr(buf,"Confirma")){
     printf("Mensagem recebida: [%s], bytes recebidos: [%d]\n",buf,n);

     SENDTO_ADDR.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
     SENDTO_ADDR.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));
     n = sendto (sock, buf,MAX_BUFFER,0,(struct sockaddr *) &SENDTO_ADDR, sendlen);



   }
    else{
    printf("Mensagem recebida: [%s], bytes recebidos: [%d]\n",buf,n);
    SENDTO_ADDR.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
    SENDTO_ADDR.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3]));
   n = sendto (sock, buf,MAX_BUFFER,0,(struct sockaddr *) &SENDTO_ADDR, sendlen);


   SENDTO_ADDR.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
   SENDTO_ADDR.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));
   strcpy(buf," Confirmado interlocutor. ");
   n = sendto (sock, buf,MAX_BUFFER,0,(struct sockaddr *) &SENDTO_ADDR, sendlen);
    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: The PC2 code results in a long string of warning messages from the compiler.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same things

Comment: OT:  in general, ALL CAPS is used for macros,  not variable names

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("USAGE: %s <a.porto> <ip_broadcast> <c.porto> <b.porto>\n",argv[0]);`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <a.porto> <ip_broadcast> <c.porto> <b.porto>\n",argv[0]);

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding:  `n = recvfrom(sock,buf,MAX_BUFFER,0,(struct sockaddr *) &FROM_ADDR, &fromlen);`  The returned type from `recvfrom()` is a `ssize_t`, not a `int`.  When calling C library functions, please read the associated MAN page and follow the typing, etc as laid out in those MAN pages

Comment: OT: regarding: `int sock, ...`  A socket is defined as a type: `sock_t`  Currently that is a 'int' but you cannot depend on that always being true

Comment: regarding `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &V, sizeof(V));`   Why are you setting that socket option if you do NOT want to use `broadcast`?

Comment: In general a `datagram` (UDP) is a one way path.  Suggest that PC1 and PC3 setup a UDP path from PC3 to PC1

Comment: the code works all the way, the only thing that is not correct is sending the confirmation from pc2 to pc1 by broadcast, and it should be via Unicast. However it works the same way, but my teacher does not want it to be this way and I do not know how to change